# Access REST API in Java with json parameters

Tags: java, json, rest

I do not know what I am doing wrong, but I cannot access a `REST API` using the `POST` method in Java with `Json` parameters.

Each time I run the program, I receive `Java.net.SocketException - Connection Reset`.

I tried to access the API from `PHP`, and it worked.

Code: https://github.com/BobTheProgrammer/Question/blob/master/POST

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
    public static void HttpPost() {
    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "https://api.website.net/auth/token");
        StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"auth\":{\"user\":{\"id\":\"bla\",\"password\":\"bla\"}\"method\":\"user\",\"website\":\"http://website.net/\"}}");
        post.setEntity(input);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: What could it be? Anyway. I need to implement the API in a android app. Since I can access it using php code,how can I get the response from the server into a text file?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the **JSON syntax** in your source code in line number 55, you have missed a comma after the user object.

Replace this line

```
String urlParameters = "{\"auth\":{\"user\":{\"id\":\"bla\",\"password\":\"bla\"}\"method\":\"user\",\"website\":\"http://website.net/\"}}";
```

with this one(added a comma after the user object before method)

```
String urlParameters = "{\"auth\":{\"user\":{\"id\":\"bla\",\"password\":\"bla\"},\"method\":\"user\",\"website\":\"http://website.net/\"}}";
```